# Yii2: Display modal from a clickable row in Gridview

Tags: gridview, yii2, modal-dialog

I want to display modal after clicking a row in Gridview but the modal content won't display.

What's missing or something wrong with my code?

In main.php:

```
    <?php
    Modal::begin([
        'header'=>'<h4>Update '. $this->title .'</h4>',
        'id'=>'update-modal',
        'size'=>'modal-md'
    ]);

echo "<div id='updateModalContent'></div>";

Modal::end();
?>
```

In index.php:

```
    <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        [
            'attribute'=>'name',
            'format'=>'raw',
            'value'=>function ($model) {
                    return Html::a($model->name, ['/unit/unit/update', 'id'=>$model->id], ['class' => 'update-modal-link',
                                                'data-toggle'=>"modal",
                                                'data-target'=>"#update-modal",
                                            ]);
             }
        ],
    ],
]); ?>
```

In main.js:

```
    $(function () { 
        $('.update-modal-link').click(function () {
            $('#update-modal')
                .modal('show')
                .find('#updateModalContent')
                .load($(this).attr('value'));
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either use javascript or the default `data-toggle` and `data-target` attributes, you are trying to load it via 2 sources and i suspect that the problem you are facing is that it loads the modal and disappears instantly.

If that is correct remove the attributes from the anchor link in your `GridView` column and update it to the below.

```
[
    'attribute' => 'name',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => function ($model) {
        return Html::a($model->name, ['/unit/unit/update', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'update-modal-link']);
    }
],
```

Then you are trying to assignthe `value` attribute for the anchor which is not valid you need to target the `href` attribute for the anchor to get the relative url and load the modal content.

Change your javascript code to below

```
$(function () { 
    $('.update-modal-link').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#update-modal')
            .modal('show')
            .find('#updateModalContent')
            .load($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @E.Baguio you are welcome, do mark the answer as correct if it worked for you